# Javascript poll and submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Am trying to get my 'Allocate auto every minute' button below to keep submitting itself every minute.

Using ASP.NET MVC3

[image]

Polling in javascript something like this.. which when I click the click button it keeps firing every 3 secs.  But how to get it to fire off a submit to the back end... hmm - this feels like an async call to MVC.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
var intervalId = 0;

$(function() {
    $('input[name=click]').bind('click', function() {
        $('.discussion').append('<div class="replyarea">some content in here plus</div>');
        intervalId = setInterval(fadeDiscussion, 3000); // start the timer
    });
});

var i = 1;
function fadeDiscussion () {
    console.log(i);
    $('.discussion').fadeOut().fadeIn();
    $('.discussion').append('<div class="replyarea">polled</div>');
    i++;
}
</script>
```

[image]

thanks to [JQuery auto refresh (setInterval)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747800/jquery-auto-refresh-setinterval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the post function in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

jQuery.post(URL, [data,] [success(data, textStatus, jqXHR),] [dataType]);

```
$.post("xxx.html", {}, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    alert("async request was completed");
});
```